# URL route path in react application

Tags: reactjs, react-router

What is the need of showing different URL path in react application, I can display all the react component conditionally on same URL path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the need of showing different URL path in react application, I
> can display all the react component conditionally on same URL path

While you *could* render a single React app component that conditionally renders dynamic content without using the URL path, using routing/navigation libraries like `react-router` allow the app to do this conditional content rendering based on the URL. In other words, instead of using internal conditions to render dynamic content the app is using the URL.

React apps are essentially [**S**ingle **P**age **A**pps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) (*SPAs*), meaning when the React app is hosted on a server only the single root `index.html` file is requested and sent over the wire.

> A single-page application (SPA) is a web application or website that
> interacts with the user by dynamically rewriting the current web page
> with new data from the web server, instead of the default method of a
> web browser loading entire new pages. The goal is faster transitions
> that make the website feel more like a native app.

Using different URL paths in the browser's address bar is an easy way to let the React app know what "page" the user is really trying to access. If all the user enters is `"https://yourDomain.com/app"` where the app is hosted, then how would they get to any specific page after the initial page load *other than* navigating there via the app's navigation? The URL path is what allows direct navigation via a browser, e.g. `"https://yourDomain.com/app/login"`.

Comment: Thanks, and if I understand correctly, the only reason to have different URL is to allow user to navigate the application through URL as well.

Comment: @KishoreGautam Yes, that is correct. Well, it may not be the ***only*** reason, but it's certainly a major one.

Answer (score 0):

If I did understand you right you mean the use of different URLs on the same website for different pages of your website. If thats the case you want to use a libary for routing. I personally like React-Router-Dom, there is great documentation on online pages and Youtube. Just search vor react-router-dom v6.

You can add it like so: `npm install react-router-dom`

if not, please elaborate your question further

Comment: I know that different URL is possible through react-router-dom, but my question is what is the need of routing, I can just have one URL and then conditionally display the content on same URL, what is the harm in that?